# how to read data of foreign key though eval using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

Just to have an idea of my database. I have two tables called brand and stringInstrumentItem. the table brand have columns called brandId,name and image. While the stringInstrumentItem have a column of itemId,brand,model and price.Normally i would be able to display data of column brand and model of table stringInstrumentItem through this code:

```
<div id="label"><%# Eval("brand") %> <%# Eval("model") %></div>
```

**The output in my webpage would be: Ibanez AB30**

But now that i'm trying to learn about relational database and foreign keys. I changed the column named brand of stringInstrumentItem to brandId. Now, the column brandId,which is the foreign key for table stringInstrumentItem references the primary key of table brand called brandId as well.

The problem is, I cannot do the same thing anymore. If i try to do this line of code:

```
<div id="label"><%# Eval("brandId") %> <%# Eval("model") %></div>
```

**It will give me this output: 1 AB30**

Instead of the actual string, it is giving me the id instead. My question is, how do i access the column called name of table brand through the relationship of brandId(foreign key) of table stringInstrumentItem to brandId(primary key) of table brand???

Take note, i haven't coded anything in my code-behind to make this work. it is all code inline. Kindly give advice and solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select statement will need now to join the 2 tables as so:

```
SELECT  brandid ,
    brand ,
    model
FROM    brand
    JOIN stringInstrumentItem ON stringInstrumentItem.brandid = brand.brandid;
```

Now you will get both, `brandid` and `brand` in the output and you can `Eval` as you need to; in this case, you will need to `<%# Eval("brand") %>` again but you will also get `brandid` if you need to perform some action based on the unique id of the brand.

**Update**

Change your SELECT statement to:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    stringInstrumentItem
        JOIN brand ON stringInstrumentItem.brandid = brand.brandid
WHERE   brandId IN ( SELECT brandId
                     FROM   brand
                     WHERE  name = @brand );
```

Comment: your code is working fine but i just want to ask how to implement this solution if currently i have a statement like this in my code: string query = "SELECT * FROM stringInstrumentItem WHERE brandId IN(SELECT brandId FROM brand WHERE name = @brand)";

Comment: @RockStar see my update but avoid doing `SELECT * FROM...` ALWAYS specify the columns you intend to use. Never more than that.

Comment: its giving me an exception : ambiguous column name 'brandId'..what does this mean?

Comment: the first solution is working but the updated version of it is giving me the exception error

Comment: @rockstar it means that both tables, `brand` and `stringInstrumentItem` have a column with the same name. You need to specify the column names with the form `table.column` (e.g. `select stringInstrumentItem.brandid, brand.brand, ..etc`

Comment: it worked perfectly! i really learned alot in this. thumbs up!